# Opencv 1080p record but show 720p

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing, video-encoding

I am recording 1080p video to file, but I need to show to user 1280*720 size. how can I do this ?  When it's 1080p, it doesn't fit on the screen, so I want to show 720p to the user and get the recording in 1080p.

This is my source code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://secret:secret@192.168.1.64/1')

    filename = user_id +'.mp4' #.avi .mp4
    frames_per_seconds = 25 #this is the standard for the movie or films
    config = CFEVideoConf(cap, filepath = filename, res='1080p')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, config.video_type, frames_per_seconds,config.dims)
    print(config.dims)
    img_path = 'ap_logo.png'
    logo = cv2.imread(img_path,-1)
    watermark = image_resize(logo, height=50)
    watermark = cv2.cvtColor(watermark, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    
    while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
    
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        frame = cv2.rotate(frame, cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)

        frame_h, frame_w, frame_c = frame.shape
        # # overlay with 4 channel BGR and Alpha
        overlay = np.zeros((frame_h, frame_w, 4), dtype='uint8')
    
        watermark_h, watermark_w, watermark_c = watermark.shape
        for i in range(0, watermark_h):
            for j in range(0, watermark_w):
                if watermark[i, j][3] != 0:
                    h_offset = frame_h - watermark_h
                    w_offset = frame_w - watermark_w
                    overlay[h_offset + i, w_offset + j] = watermark[i, j]
    
        cv2.addWeighted(overlay, 0.25, frame, 1.0, 0, frame)
    
        # Display the resulting frame
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
        if ret:
            # cv2.resize(1280, 720)
            cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
            # cv2.resize(frame, 720,1280, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    
            # cv2.namedWindow('Frame', cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
    
            # cv2.resizeWindow('Frame', 720, 1280)
    
            out.write(frame)  # file a ilgili frame yazılıyor
    
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break
    
    
    #When everything done, relase the capture
    cap.release()
    out.release() # saved
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: use PyAV. that's for encoding/decoding video. OpenCV is not for encoding video or for drawing, it's for _computer vision_ (automatic understanding of images/video).

Comment: Possible solution: `cv2.imshow('Frame', cv2.resize(frame, [1280, 720]))`